# Does pymysql's lastrowid function work properly in cases of multiple users inserting into DB?

Tags: mysql, flask, pymysql

I have 2 tables in my DB purchase order and lines. Every order can have multiple lines(one line for each part ordered). I am developing an application where an order will first be created. Need to get the ID of this order and then insert lines later on(as the user adds the parts). How can I ensure ther correct value of order ID is fetched?

Comment: I can't comment on pymysql, but will observer that mysql's LAST_INSERT_ID() function is session-specific.

Answer (score 0):

I cant understand what you exactly want but you should search about ORM its maybe can help you.